# Smalltalk - Is it possible to add a string to a String instance via a method?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Smalltalk - Is it possible to add a string to a String instance via a method?

Essentially I'd like something along the lines of:

```
renderThisOn: aString

aString append: 'whatever text I want'
```

Essentially I'd like a String instance (ByteString, etc) to behave like the "html" object in Seaside. I pass it on as an argument to multiple methods, each adding some information to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a practical viewpoint the answer would be no, it is not possible to change the size of a String. You can modify the characters of the String though:

```
a := 'abc'.
a at: 2 put: $x.
a = 'axc' "true"
```

Therefore, when you concatenate two strings you get a third one, while the others two remain unchanged

```
s := 'abc'.
t := 'def'.
u := s , t.
s = 'abc'. "true"
t = 'def'. "true"
```

Having said this, there is actually a way to do grow (or shrink) a String. The idea is to use `become:` (or `becomeForward:`). This message will replace all references to the receiver with references to the argument. In your case:

```
s := 'abc'.
t := 'def'.
assoc := s -> 3 "referene to s"
s become: s , t.
s = 'abcdef'. "true"
assoc key == s "true"
```

The reason why I started my answer by saying that you cannot change the string's size is because in the vast majority of cases the use of `become:` is overkilling and the recommended practice is to review the code and eliminate the need for modifying the structure of an object.

Comment: I see. Essentially you are telling me that "in general" one wants to avoid changing a variable's "value" while it's "address" stays unchanged? Essentially parts of the program have already used the "value" at that "address" in it current form, I then change it, now the program keeps on going uses the reference (address) to that value again and gets another "value" in response. Instead this "become:" goes around this limitation by taking the "address" of the new "value" and replacing the other objects's references to the old "address" with the new "address", this being overkill.

Comment: Or is this just a size issue. I can't grow it?

Comment: @unmircea Yes, your first comment is correct. It is also a size issue. Objects have a header and several fields for their instance variables, all of this in contiguous memory. In the case of Strings their structure could leave between 0 and 3 unused bytes (32 bits). Therefore supporting grow is generally impossible. The main point, however, is that applications almost invariably wouldn't take advantage of a growing feature. GemStone is to my knowledge the only Smalltalk that allows fixed sized objects (e.g. Arrays) to grow in size.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia Smalltalk/X also allows to grow an Array, but you get a warning.  For example: `t := Array new: 3.
t at: 1 put: 'first'.
t at: 2 put: 'second'.
t at: 3 put: 'third'.
t add: 'forth'. "is actually added"
t inspect.`

Comment: @tukan Interesting. In GemStone you can also grow an `Array`.

Answer (score 3):

String literals in Smalltalk are immutable objects.

It is possible different ways:

Pass instance of WriteStream

```
renderThisOn: aWriteStream
    aWriteStream nextPutAll: 'whatever text I want'
```

You can create own class wrapper around String and pass its instance:

```
renderThisOn: aStringWrapper
    aStringWrapper append: 'whatever text I want'
```

Streams are more preferable, because streams are faster than string concatenation

Answer (score 2):

comma method:

```
|a|
a := 'abc'.
a,'def'
```

`ctrl+p` and get `'abcdef'`

Comment: Add a forth line of code to that. "a inspect" and then "Do It" on the whole lot. A is still 'abc'. I need something like 'a := 'abc'. a append: 'def'. a inspect' and a will be 'abcdef'

Comment: well, my answer is wrong. Strings in Pharo is mutable (`#at:put:` works). But method `#add:` and `#addAll:` not implemented. I can't find more related method.

Comment: @unmircea In Smalltalk you cannot modify a String by making it larger. You have to replace it with the concatenation, which is a new instance. Note however that you could use become: to "modify" your original String, but that would be (most likely) overkilling.

Comment: "by making it larger" you mean having more letters than it started with. I can change the letters with new ones, but never exceed the initial length. I can't "grow" it, in your words "modify to make it larger".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to use it, a string holder can achieve what you need. The simplest might be to pass an array with the first and only element being the string you want to alter in different methods. The array won't change but the one and only element will change as you place different strings there. More complex would be to create a specialised string holder class, with a field that holds the string which changes. You can then implement the common string methods on that holder, to redirect to the current actual string.